# How to pass an array to http POST on IONIC?

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to make a POST into a determinate URL, i achieve this with POSTMAN but i don't receive anything trying it with http...

I need to POST an array with this parameters:

```
fos_user_registration_form[email]:aa@a.com
fos_user_registration_form[plainPassword][first]:123456789
fos_user_registration_form[plainPassword][second]:123456789
```

And my function is like this, but i didn't receive the correct response:

```
submitRegistration(value): void{
let link = 'http://apilink.com/';
let myData = {
  fos_user_registration_form: {
  _token: this.data.token,
  username: value.user,
  email: value.mail,
  plainPassword: {
    first: value.pass,
    second: value.confirmPass
  },
  userLocalization: value.village}};

this.http.post(link, myData)
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.data.response = data["_body"];
  }, error => {
    alert("Oooops!");
  });
```

}

Maybe the array is bad formed? I don't know.. Can't someone help me, please?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any array?

Comment: It's ley mydata

Comment: That's not an array. Can you see the posting of the data in your network tab of your browser? And what is the response?

Comment: I see in the console log than is a object.. Who can i transform into an array?

Comment: Please update your question with how the object looks like that is send, and what you expect it to be

Comment: @Specimen you are extracting a string value of your response, is that intended? Don't you want the json?

Comment: Nope, i want the string because in a future i'll need that string to check a field from that response.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried by adding headers

```
var headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type': 'application/json');
let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
let myData= {
   //put your required date to pass
}
this.http.post(link, myData, options)
.subscribe(data => {
this.data.response = data["_body"];
}, error => {
alert("Oooops!");
});

}
```

if you use it like this it may work. try using token like this instead of sending it on object. i have not worked with ionic two but i worked on ionic one.

Comment: This didn't worked... I need to pass all parameters to the post, not only the token or the token in the header..